# Add getters and setters to a set of variables

Tags: java, regex, sed

Any improvements are welcome.

a.bat

```
sed -r "s/private (.*) (.*);(.*)/&\npublic \1 get\u\2(){return \2;}\npublic void set\u\2(\u\2){this.\2=\u\2;}\n/" "%~1">"%~2"
```

in:

```
private String firstName;// Stores firstName
private String lastName;
private String address;
```

using `a.bat in out`

out:

```
private String firstName;// Stores firstName
public String getFirstName(){return firstName;}
public void setFirstName(FirstName){this.firstName=FirstName;}

private String lastName;
public String getLastName(){return lastName;}
public void setLastName(LastName){this.lastName=LastName;}

private String address;
public String getAddress(){return address;}
public void setAddress(Address){this.address=Address;}
```

To do:
add javadoc generation to methods.

Comment: Is this an exercise? Just because most IDEs do this out of the box. Otherwise I think it's an elegant solution :)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't really look into the IDE, since I use mostly a separate editor.

Comment: `private String firstName;// Stores firstName
` You may know it, I say it anyway...do not comment what is obvious. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the parameter type in the setter methods (including @blufox suggestion):

```
sed -r "s/private\s+([^; ]+)\s+([^; ]+)\s*;(.*)$/&\npublic \1 get\u\2(){return \2;}\npublic void set\u\2(\1 \2){this.\2=\u\2;}\n/" "%~1">"%~2"
```

which produces:

```
private String firstName;// Stores firstName
public String getFirstName(){return firstName;}
public void setFirstName(String firstName){this.firstName=FirstName;}
```

**But**: you better use an IDE (e.g., Eclipse) for these tasks. You are trying to parse Java code with a regex which is a bad idea.

Just some examples:

- declarations could be on different lines

  ```
  private String // some comment
      myVariableOnTheNextLine
      // some other comment
      ; // semicolon
  ```
- the `public` or `private` modifier could be omitted

  ```
  String myString;
  ```
- fields can be initialized

  ```
  String myString = "my string";
  ```
- fields can be declared final

  ```
  private final String myString;
  ```
- and so on

Answer (score 0):

`s/private (.*) (.*);(.*)`
This may be better done as `s/private ([^; ]+) +([^; ]+) *;(.*)$`

This avoids matching semicolon and space in the type and variable name.
(Be as restrictive in your match as you can.)